# how to check whether foreign key is working or not in symfony2 with doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have followed [One-to-Many relation not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448075/one-to-many-relation-not-working) and created a one to many relationship

i have a users table where i have following fields

```
 - id(primary key) 
 - name 
 - pwd
```

i have attachments table where user can upload more than one file i.e one user_id contains multiple files

```
  - id
  - user_id(foreignkey)
  - path
```

my user entity contains the following code

```
namespace Repair\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * users
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\usersRepository")
 */

class users
{

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;
--some code --

/**

* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="attachments", mappedBy="user_id")

*/

private $attachments;


public function __construct()

{

    $this->attachments= new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Add attachments
 *
 * @param \Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\attachments $attachments
 * @return users
 */
public function addAttachment(\Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\attachments $attachments)
{
    $this->attachments[] = $attachments;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove attachments
 *
 * @param \Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\attachments $attachments
 */
public function removeAttachment(\Repair\StoreBundle\Entity\attachments $attachments)
{
    $this->attachments->removeElement($attachments);
}

/**
 * Get attachments
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getAttachments()
{
    return $this->attachments;
}
```

this is my attachments entity

```
namespace Repair\StoreBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * attachments
*/
class attachments
{
       -- some code for id--

private $id;

/**
 * @var integer

 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)

 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="users")

 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")

 */

protected $userId;

public function getId()

{

    return $this->id;

}
/**

 * Set userId

 * @param integer $userId

 * @return attachments

 */

public function setUserId($userId)

{

    $this->userId = $userId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get userId
 *
 * @return integer

 */

public function getuserId() 

{

    return $this->userId;

}

   --Some code for paths -- 
}
```

It is not displaying any errors 
 but how to know whether the foriegn key is set or not i went to phpmyadmin and checked the indexes it only shows the primary keys.please say whether i did correct or not and how to check whether foreign key is set or not

Comment: Your best bet might be to work through the doctrine manual: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html.  Doctrine deals with objects so all this user_id stuff should be user.

Answer (score 0):

problem is in your annotations. In your attachment entity you should have annotation like this.

```
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="users", inversedBy="annotations")
```

you don't have to have join column annotation. But if you want to have it there, it should look like this.

```
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
```

Also it shouldn't be called `user_id` but `user`, because doctrine takes it as whole entity.

Comment: do i need to change the user_id column to user but what happens if it is user_is.do i need to change in @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false) and protected $user in this way

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you paste here both entities? Only attributes, without methods.